# Prove that a function lies in $L^1$ and in $W^{(1,1)}$ for some parameter

Tags: integration, analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

I want to do the following tasks

Let $G:=B_1(0)\subset \mathbb R^2$ be the open ball around $0$ with radius 2 in the norm $||\cdot||$ and $u_{\rho}(x)=||x||^{\rho}_2$, $x\in G$. Show the following

a) $u_p \in L^1(G)$, if $\rho>-2$

b) $u_p\in W^{(1,1)}(G)$, if $\rho>-1$ , where $W^{k,p}$ is the [Sobolev-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space).

For a):

I used substitution: $x=rcos(\phi)$, $y=rsin(\phi)$, to obtain:

$\int_G||x||_2^{\rho}dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 r^p\cdot r drd\phi=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 r^{p+1}\cdot  drd\phi$ which is finite if $\rho>-2$.

I guess this should be correct.

But I don't know how to show the other task.

I have to show that the partial derivatives of $u_p$ are in $L^1$?

Comment: Yes, the first part is correct. For the second, too, you need to study the partial derivatives. Or, which is equiavalent, the norm of the gradient.

Comment: Okay, since this function is symmetric in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$, we just consider the partial derivative in terms of $x_1$, which is $2x_1\cdot \rho/2(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{\rho/2-1}$, but how can I show, that its in $L^1$? I guess substitution is not an option in this case.

Comment: Polar coordinates should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. One question left: the sobolev space is defined with weak derivatives. But this does not matter for us, because our function $u_p$ is "normal differentiable"? I guess there might be a problem, because there is a pole in $(0,0)$ for some $\rho$

Comment: A point has measure zero. You can prove that the weak derivative is equal to what you've written almost everywhere, so no problem there.